# How to config xCode 4 to compile objective-c++ without adding a '.mm' file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, objective-c++

I am trying to describe my problem clearly for you, so it might be a little long, and I really appreciate that if you can read it and provide some suggestion. Thanks.

I have a library project, let's call it `MyCppLib`, which contains some legacy c++ code, and I add a adapter class in this project so that I can use it with out using objective-c++ in other project. Here is an overview of `MyCppLib` project.

**Project *MyCppLib***
- *some legacy c++ code*
- Adapter.h
- Adapter.mm

I have another project, let's call it `Main` project, which use the `MyCppLib` project as a static library. So I use xCode 4 to compile `MyCppLib`, and get `libMyCppLib.a`, and config `Main` project in xCode 4 to link it with `Main` project. Here is an overview of `Main` project.

**Project *Main***
- *Some objective-c classes* **which DO NOT contain '.mm' file**
- Adapter.h
- libMyCppLib.a *as a static library*

While I compile the `Main` project in xCode 4 I get some errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>    "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>        -[Adapter init] in libMyCppLib.a(Adapter.o)
>        *my*::*cpp*::*namespace*::*MyCppClass*::*MyCppClass*()in libMyCppLib.a(*MyCppClass*.o)
>
> ... *some other similar errors*
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I figure it might because the `Main` project do not have an objective-c++ capability, so I add a '.mm' file to the `Main` project. And now `Main` project should be like this:

**Project *Main***
- *Some objective-c classes* **which DO NOT contain '.mm' file**
- Adapter.h
- libMyCppLib.a *as a static library*
- DummyObjCpp.h
- DummyObjCpp.mm

Then, I compile the `Main` project, and it **succeed**!

So, *finally*, my question is: how can I configure the `Main` project to have objective-c++ capability without adding a '.mm' file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've read over the question a few times, but I'm still not sure I understand the problem.

While I've done a lot with Objective-C, C++, and Objective-C++, I haven't encountered the scenario you've described with static libraries (since most of my development is for OS X rather than iOS, where dynamic libraries are allowed and preferred).

It sounds like there might be an issue in your second project because the .h file by itself doesn't tell enough about what's contained in the .a (namely that when you combine it with the rest of your executable, you'll need to be linked against `libstdc++.dylib`). You might try changing the "File Type" of the `Adapter.h` header file from the default of `C header` to `C++ header` as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Or add libstdc++.dylib to the list of linked libraries.

Comment: @NSGod Sorry about my poor English. I tried you suggestion of changing file type, but it still not work. But the solution of @Bavarious which is also mentioned in your answer works! Thank you